# How to post rails without saving to database?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, forms, post

I would really just like to compare values for a user from the database without saving any of his inputs to the database. Basically I would like to replicate the following functionality in PHP to Rails:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
 <input type="text" name="title" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {echo $_POST["title"];}
?>
```

What would be the source to do an identical thing in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is in your controller action simple you can do the comparison process without saving the params into you database. Let say your controller is posts controller.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Your code here for comparison
  end
end
```

Still you have any help please let me know.

Comment: Okay, but in that case - how do I have to name my input fields if I'm not using a model for them?

Comment: Ok, Lets say params => { title: 'Entered Title' }.  So in your controller you will get params[:title] to be 'Entered Title'. So you can proceed to compare the title with any other values. It should be like if params[:title] == 'Not Entered Title'....